# How can I convert many different document formats to PDF on UNIX?

Tags: unix, pdf, file-conversion

There are a few SaaS providers out there who do this sort of thing, but I do not want to rely on a 3rd party. I am looking for a (preferrably open source) locally hosted UNIX command line library to take in hundreds of different document formats (doc, docx, csv, xls, txt, tiff, etc etc), and convert them to PDFs. So:

1. Is there a simple, unified library that can do this, or will I need to deal with a hodge-podge of libraries?
2. What library/libraries can get the job done?

If there are good paid libraries available, I'd also be interested in learning about them. But open source is the preferred route.

Answer (score 0):

The most mature open source for this is OpenOffice,
which can be run "headless" (no UI), as descirbed at:

http://code.google.com/p/openmeetings/wiki/OpenOfficeConverter

You can use the Apache.org branch of OpenOffice,
which is reportedly faster than LibreOffice,
and is under a more permissive license.